# Managing shaders in OpenGL - A Shader class

Tags: c++, opengl

I've create a basic `Shader` class in modern OpenGL (*3.1*) which **works perfectly**, though it is not feature complete yet. It still lacks the functionality to allow the user registering *uniform variables* in the shader and update them by calling a method.

Suggestions on how to further advance the implementation are welcome, otherwise, any suggestions and improvements regarding the current code are also appreciated.

**Shader.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "LogManager.h"
#include "Transform.h"
#include "camera.h"

namespace deprecate
{

class Shader
{
public:

    Shader(const std::string& fileName);
    virtual ~Shader();

    void Bind();
    void UnBind();
    void Update(const Transform& transform, const Camera& camera, float time);

    Shader& operator=(const Shader& shader) = delete;
    Shader(const Shader& shader) = delete;

private:
    static const unsigned int NUM_SHADERS = 2;

    enum{
        TRANSFORM_U,
        TIME_U,
        NUM_UNIFORMS
    };

    std::string LoadShader(const std::string& fileName);
    void CheckShaderError(GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool isProgram, const char* msg);
    GLuint CreateShader(const std::string& text, GLenum type);

    GLuint m_program;
    GLuint m_shaders[NUM_SHADERS];
    GLuint m_uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];
};
}
```

**Shader.cpp**:

```
#include "Shader.h"

namespace deprecate{

Shader::Shader(const std::string& fileName){
    m_program = glCreateProgram();
    m_shaders[0] = CreateShader(LoadShader(fileName + ".vert"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    m_shaders[1] = CreateShader(LoadShader(fileName + ".frag"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++)
        glAttachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);

    glBindAttribLocation(m_program, 0, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(m_program, 1, "texCoord");
    glBindAttribLocation(m_program, 2, "normal");

    glLinkProgram(m_program);
    CheckShaderError(m_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, true, "ERROR LNK shader program");

    glValidateProgram(m_program);
    CheckShaderError(m_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, true, "ERROR INV shader program");

    m_uniforms[TRANSFORM_U] = glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "transform");
    m_uniforms[TIME_U] = glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "time");
}

Shader::~Shader(){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++)
    {
        glDetachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);
        glDeleteShader(m_shaders[i]);
    }
    glDeleteProgram(m_program);
}

void Shader::Bind(){
    glUseProgram(m_program);
}

void Shader::UnBind(){
    glUseProgram(0);
}

void Shader::Update(const Transform& transform, const Camera& camera, float time){
    glm::mat4 model = camera.GetMVP() *  transform.GetModel();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniforms[TRANSFORM_U], 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);
    glUniform1f(m_uniforms[TIME_U], time);
}

std::string Shader::LoadShader(const std::string& fileName){
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open((fileName).c_str());

    std::string output;
    std::string line;

    if (file.is_open()){
        while (file.good()){
            getline(file, line);
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    else
        LOG_ERROR("ShaderLoader", "ERROR : Failed to load shader");

    file.close();
    return output;
}

void Shader::CheckShaderError(GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool isProgram, const char* msg){
    GLint success = 0;
    GLchar error[1024] = { 0 };

    if (isProgram)
        glGetProgramiv(shader, flag, &success);
    else
        glGetShaderiv(shader, flag, &success);

    if (success == GL_FALSE){
        if (isProgram)
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(error), NULL, error);
        else
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, sizeof(error), NULL, error);

        std::cout << msg << " : " << error << " " << std::endl;
    }
}


GLuint Shader::CreateShader(const std::string& text, GLenum type)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);

    if (shader == 0)
        LOG_ERROR("Shader", "ERROR : FAILED to create shader");

    const GLchar* shaderSource[1];
    shaderSource[0] = text.c_str();
    GLint lengths[1];
    lengths[0] = text.length();

    glShaderSource(shader, 1, shaderSource, lengths);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    CheckShaderError(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, false, "ERROR : Shader compilation failed");
    return shader;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have access to a sensible compiler that supports C++11 or newer.

1. Don't place filesystem IO in your shader class.
2. Consider using `glGetAttriblocation` instead of `glBindAttribLocation`, but that's subjective.
3. Don't use `static const unsigned int` to store the length of an array, use std::array instead.
4. Your `CheckShaderError` is bipolar with regards to `isProgram`. Just create two methods.
5. If you are hard coding file extensions, don't call your variable `fileName`, because it is not a file's name.
6. `glValidateProgram` should be called just before `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`. It tests whether the current 'setup' or 'context' is valid for drawing actions - in your constructor, the context is not setup. (OpenGL ES is generally more strict about this)
7. Your `Update` method seems useless, my own projects have many shaders with many different inputs (normal transform, shadow maps, light sources, etc).
8. Your error checking is weird. If `LoadShader` yields an error, you still continue executing and call `CreateShader`.
9. I don't believe OpenGL 3.1 is 'modern'. Version 4.3 is 'modern'.
10. If `unsigned int i` is used to access indices, just use `size_t` - it's less typing.
11. `GLchar error[1024]` don't assume 1024 bytes is enough. Just query for the log length, and allocate bytes based on that. This is what I did:

    ```
    GLint logLength = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);

    if (logLength > 0) {
        auto log = std::unique_ptr<char>(new char[logLength]);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLength, &logLength, log.get());
        printf("Shader compile log:\n%s", log.get());
    }
    ```
12. `const GLchar* shaderSource[1];` is the same as `const GLchar* shaderSource;`
13. Your destructor deletes stuff, without validating whether they were created to begin with.
14. I think your `Bind` and `UnBind` methods are vague. Pretty much anything in OpenGL needs to be bound.
15. Calling your namespace `deprecate` is possibly confusing.
16. `else
        LOG_ERROR("ShaderLoader", "ERROR : Failed to load shader");`
     worries me. Notice the missing parenthesis. What do you think will happen if you `#undef` your macro?
17. Having no assignment operator, default constructor, copy constructor nor a move constructor, can you use an `std::vector` of `Shaders`? This is more a broad thing about usability of your classes. I like things flexible, but that's subjective.

Comment: 1) Thanks ! Yes, I have g++ 11, visual c++ 11

Comment: 7) "Your Update method seems useless" : OK, but how should I update my camera, transform, time uniforms… then ?

Comment: 9) I consider it has modern, compared to the other versions of opengl; there were really big changes;

Comment: Can you show me your shader class' update, and check error parts, so I can see what you're referring to ? ( OR if you can, the entire class would be a good idea ! )